# common neighbors between nodes in a graph

Tags: python, graph

I create a graph of four nodes 1, 2, 3, 4 and three edges (1,2), (1,3), (2,3), then I get the common neighbors between two nodes of them as follows:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
h=[1,2,3,4]
G.add_nodes_from(h)
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)])
cnbors = list(nx.common_neighbors(G, 1, 3))
print(cnbors)
```

But I want to get the common neighbors for many nodes and edges stored in csv files.

I've tried this code:

```
node= pd.read_csv("vectorcornell.csv", names=["n"])
edges=pd.read_csv("edgescornell.csv", names=["u", "v"])
G.add_nodes_from("n")
G.add_edges_from([("u","v")])
cnbors = list(nx.common_neighbors(G, "u", "v"))
print(cnbors)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

Where the `vectorcornell.csv` file has one column that holds the node number and the `edgescornell.csv` file has 2 columns to hold the edges between two nodes (node number, node number).
But it doesn't store the common neighbors for all nodes.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by it not giving common neighbors for all nodes? Did you get some of them? And for adding nodes and edges, why are you using "n", "u", "v" instead of using variables `node`, `edges`?

Comment: yes, it is giving common neighbors of nodes of first edge only but i want to all nodes